# How to close java Applet through code

Tags: java, applet

I am developing a java applet. I want it to be closed by the code. I have used `System.Exit(0)` but it is not working. Is there any other method to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
applet.getAppletContext().showDocument("ThanksForUsingOurApplet.html");
```

As to the comment that a signed applet can call `System.exit(n)`.

It can in some browser/JRE combos., it can't in others.  In the ones that it can, it *shouldn't* since an applet may share a VM with other applets (less common these days), and even if not, it is the user's responsibility to close an applet by closing the page.

**An applet is a guest in a web page.  Calling `System.exit(n)` is like burning down the guest house.**

Answer (score 2):

An applet cannot call `System.exit(int);`. Security permissions don't let an applet do this.
And if you are  trying to close the browser window, even if you signed the code and the browser/user trusted you, the browser wouldn't let you shutdown/close the browser window.

If all you want to do is close a Window/Frame created from the applet, this is no different than closing a window outside of an applet.

Comment: I don't know why, but System.exit(0); works well in signed applet.

Comment: @VladimirIvanov  In which version of which browser on which OS are you claiming it 'works well'?  Last time I tested it, it led to horrible results on most browsers, and even ended (as in crashed) one browser.  Seeing it 'work' in your current version of IE (or whatever) means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove java applet code by javascript.
Example your html:

```
<button onclick="clickButton()">Click me</button>
<div id="appletCode">
     <applet width="200" height="200" archive="ImageIconApplet.jar"
        code="com.whitefang34.ImageIconApplet" name="test"/> 
</div>
```

your javascript code:

```
function clickButton(){
     var SS = document.getElementById("appletCode");
    SS.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As said above,exiting applet is simple by adding System.exit(0) in if(condition) for which you want to close the applet.Though I am describing of 
applet viewer.But,it certainly works fine.