# run time error while closing the applet

Tags: java, applet

i want to know how to read these errors; please anyone help me out. The following error is displayed after closing an applet

```
C:\Users\Radha G\Desktop\practice>appletviewer NewApplet.html
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: acc
ess denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:264)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
427)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:744)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:88)
        at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:869)
        at SimpleApplet.actionPerformed(SimpleApplet.java:50)
        at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:388)
        at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:356)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchTh
read.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:163)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Comment: first tell that what is your applet code ...

Comment: my code is for closing the applet by pressing the "exit button",i am using appletviewer.

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace:

```
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:869)  <---- nooo!
    at SimpleApplet.actionPerformed(SimpleApplet.java:50)
```

You cannot call `System.exit()` from an applet.

See [How to close java Applet through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507108/how-to-close-java-applet-through-code) for a suggestion of how you can close your applet the correct way.

Comment: i am new for iava i am not getting how to do/add applet.getAppletContext().showDocument("ThanksForUsingOurApplet.html"); please suggest me.

Comment: @radha Perhaps add a comment under one of the answers in that other question?

Comment: k. i am using appletviewer, tell me how to close it by pressing the exit buuton